# Interpreting the Jordan Normal Form

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

What's the best way to interpret Jordan Normal Form (e.g. in terms of a linear map)?

For instance, how should we interpret those $1$'s?

Answer (score 1):

Interpret those 1's as shearing everything in the subspace of the block that is not in the direction of the unique (up to multiple) eigenvector of the block.